# compare two directory trees

Tags: diff, stdin

I have two music libraries, one a newer version than the other. I would like to compare them to figure which files I need to copy from new music tree to old.

I have tried `diff --brief -r /oldmusicdir/ /newmusicdir/` based on another user's suggestion but ^C the process after fifteen minutes (I'm guessing diff is scanning the music files themselves -- which is not necessary).

Then I tried `find /oldmusicdir/ -type d | sort > oldmusicdir` for old and new, then ran `diff oldmusicdir newmusicdir` However, since I stored the music directories in separate locations every single entry was flagged.

Next I tried running `find /musicdir/ -type d | basename -s - | sort > musicdir` but then my musicdir file simply read "-"

Does anyone know how to get basename to accept from STDIN? Or, does anyone have a better way of quickly comparing two music directories?

Thanks!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The `rsync` utility first popped into my mind when I saw your question.  Doing something like below could quickly show what files are in directory `a` but not in `b`:

```
$ rsync -rcnv a/* b/

-r will recurse into the directories
-c will compare based on file checksum
-n will run it as a "dry run" and make no changes, but just print out the files 
   that would be updated
-v will print the output to stdout verbosely
```

This is a good option because you can compare the contents of the files as well to make sure they match.  `rsync`'s delta algorithm is optimized for this type of use case.  Then if you want to make `b` match the contents of `a`, you can just remove the `-n` option to perform the actual sync.

Some related questions:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19396718/compare-files-in-two-directory-on-remote-server-using-unix
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57305/rsync-compare-directories

Comment: Rsync seems like a very powerful program. Definitely worth my time to get to know. Running `rsync -nv --delete a/ b/ | grep deleting` gave me a list of the files that existed on b but not a. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

How about generating a recursive directory listing of each directory into separate files and then using `diff` on those two files?

Comment: Cool. Good idea, but it still does /path/albumname so all albums are flagged when I run diff since they have different paths.

Comment: `diff --recursive --quiet --new-file dir1/ dir2/`

Answer (score 1):

If you like using some GUI-based utility, you can try some comparison tool: under Windows, my favorite is Total Commander (homepage: https://www.ghisler.com): it has a quite flexible feature that allows to compare and sync entire directory trees; a quick Diff tool is also present, allowing you to inspect the differences encoutered (useful for code lines, less for binary files).

In *ux, I know there's Midnight Commander, but I never tried it and I'm not sure if the same feature is present.

Anyway, Wikipedia has a page where the most used comparison tools are listed: maybe you can find some useful information there: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_comparison_tools

Max

Answer (score 1):

Another option is `comm`

```
comm -3 <(cd oldmusicdir/ ; find . | sort) <(cd newmusicdir/ ; find . | sort)
```

Note the `cd` which will make sure the locations listed will be relative to each base folder.

From the `comm` manpage:

```
NAME
       comm - compare two sorted files line by line

SYNOPSIS
       comm [OPTION]... FILE1 FILE2

DESCRIPTION
       Compare sorted files FILE1 and FILE2 line by line.
<snip>
-3     suppress column 3 (lines that appear in both files)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be the use of process substitution to pass to `diff` two "on demand" file descriptors that each hold stdout from the commands.

Example comparing the leaf-node files in each only:

```
diff -y \
  <(find /oldmusicdir -type f | xargs basename | sort -V) \
  <(find /newmusicdir -type f | xargs basename | sort -V)
```

Of course you can do whatever parsing/formatting of the output of `find` to match them up as you see fit.