# unix - sort content of two folders then compare using diff command

Tags: unix, shell-script, ksh

How do I `sort` contents of two different folders before comparing those two directories using `diff`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [compare two directory trees](http://superuser.com/questions/734548/compare-two-directory-trees)

Comment: can't use `rsync`. says not found

Comment: can I use `comm` in this?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `diff` with [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html):

```
diff <(ls -a dir1/) <(ls -a dir2/)
```

- `<(...)` creates a file descriptor whose path is added as argument to `diff`.
- When no sort option is given, `ls` sort the output alphabetically.
- The two `ls`-outputs are give to `diff` for comparsion.

My example folders look like this:

```
.
├── dir1
│   ├── file1
│   ├── file2
│   └── file3
└── dir2
    ├── file2
    ├── file3
    └── file4
```

The output is this case is:

```
$ diff <(ls -a dir1/) <(ls -a dir2/)
3d2
< file1
5a5
> file4
```